# How to add the bootargs parameter between the bootcmds parameters

Tags: linux-kernel, console, u-boot

These days I'm playing with my old ARM Chromebook model "SNOW". As you probably know,this kind of Netbook can load an external operating system using the sd card slot or the usb port. Unfortunately,my Chromebook has the sd card slot broken. So,what I want to do is to load Linux using the usb port. I've bought one converter from sd card to usb and I've installed Devuan 5 on the sd card ; I have inserted the sd card inside the adapter and would like to boot Linux (Devuan 5) through it. The u-boot version that I have installed is special because the code contains the patches needed to enable kvm. You should also know that the parameters to boot Linux are embedded inside the code,as you can see below :

https://github.com/virtualopensystems/u-boot/blob/eecfeb578e296ef3b739ac918a39b6c177dff58a/include/configs/snow.h#L101

now. I've tried many times to recompile it,trying to change the root device from /dev/mmcblk1p4 to /dev/sda4,because sda4 is the root device now,because the Linux files are stored on the sd card,partition 4,but I failed every time. Now I want to use another method to bypass the "root=/dev/mmcblk1p4" parameter. This is what I did :

```
setenv bootcmd "usb start ; usb dev 0 ; ext2load usb 
0:3 0x80008000 uImage ; ext2load usb 0:3 0x43000000  
exynos5250-snow.dtb ; bootargs console=tty1 root=/dev/
sda4 rw rootwait clk_ignore_unused --no-log ; bootm 
0x80008000 - 0x43000000"
saveenv
boot
```

Well,it does not work because despite the fact that I have said to choose sda4 as the root device,it persists to use mmcblk1p4. This is the message reported :

```
waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk1p4
sda attached SCSI removable disk...
```

I would like to know if I have written the parameters correctly. I don't see errors. The only problem is that it does not pick sda4.

Let me know,thanks.

Comment: Clearly off topic here.

Comment: Before to post it,I've checked that a similar question was allowed and I found this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77300109/how-to-make-u-boot-to-load-rootfs-from-2nd-partition-of-sd-card ; it is indeed similar to mine and it has been accepted.

Comment: "*Well,it does not work ...*" - Because the command line is not constructed properly. Each semicolon in that command line ends that command. So the U-Boot CLI then expects another command. So the "commands" in your assignment are (1) usb, (2) usb, (3) ext2load, (4) ext2load, (5) bootargs, and (6) bootm. But "bootargs" is just an environment variable, and is not a U-Boot command (that would change the value of bootargs). Your intent is to assign a new value to the "bootargs" environment variable. So you need to use the **setenv** command, i.e. `setenv bootargs console=...`.

Comment: I would argue that passing arguments to someone else's code is not _software development_.  The question you cited is at least tagged embedded-linux, so is presumably a platform on which the asker will be developing code, though I would argue that too is off-topic.  Opinions differ, and some marginal cases may be tolerated.  If there is no consensus your question will stand - good luck.